# AggregateBykey using python sets

Tags: python, scala, pyspark

i have come across the following scala example which explains aggregateByKey.
Scala Example:

```
val pairs=sc.parallelize(Array(("a",3),("a",1),("b",7),("a",5)))
import scala.collection.mutable.HashSet
//the initial value is a void Set. Adding an element to a set is the first
//_+_ Join two sets is the  _++_
val sets = pairs.aggregateByKey(new HashSet[Int])(_+_, _++_)
sets.collect
```

output of above scala code is:

```
res5: Array[(String, scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[Int])]  =Array((b,Set(7)), (a,Set(1, 5, 3)))
```

I rewrote the above scala code in python:

```
pair = sc.parallelize([("a",3),("a",1),("b",7),("a",5)])
sets=pair.aggregateByKey((set()),(lambda x,y:x.add(y)),(lambda x,y:x|y))
sets.collect()
```

i don't know what is wrong. Python code returns the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'
```

Comment: Generally speaking, that would mean that you're adding a None to the set. An instance of None is being called to be added in the chained aggregation. So the error. What does `pair.aggregateByKey((set()),(lambda x,y:x.add(y)),(lambda x,y:x|y)).collect()` give, unassigned to sets?

Comment: I would like to generate the following output: (b,Set(7)), (a,Set(1, 5, 3))            So, I have created an empty set and adding elements to set based on the key.

Comment: Ref to my comment before, what does that code snippet give without assigning to sets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function `add` updates the set and returns a `NoneType` (it doesn't return the updated set). This `NoneType` is then passed to the next iteration of the function, hence the error you get. You function should return the set:

```py
def my_add(x, y):
    x.add(y)
    return x
sets = pair.aggregateByKey(set(), my_add, lambda x, y: x|y)
sets.collect()

    [('b', {7}), ('a', {1, 3, 5})]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution

```py
sets = pair.aggregateByKey(set(), lambda x,y:x|{y}, lambda x, y: x|y)
```